# Special treatment for empty stream

Tags: kotlin, java-stream

There are tons applications for `Stream`s and in many of them one might wish to give the case that the stream completely empty a special treatment. For example, a query result set could be represented as a stream that is then rendered into a table, but if the stream is empty, I may want to display just a message "no results found".

What I'm looking for is a way to turn a `Stream` into an `Optional<Stream>` such that if a value is present it is guaranteed to be non-empty (i.e. will produce at least one element).

Of course, I could collect the `Stream` into a `Collection`, test it for non-emptiness, and re-stream it. But that is obviously not an optimal solution.

Comment: Why not implement a table UI that displays a “no results found” message when there are no rows? Or, in other words, why taint the application logic with something that is a UI issue?

Comment: I would not recommend taking this approach; streams are really intended to only have one query done on them, and emptiness is a query.  I would strongly recommend instead making decisions about handling the empty stream in your postprocessing.

Comment: @Holger I agree; this was just intended as a motivational example (not too well chosen)

Answer (score 0):

I used Kotlin's extension feature to add a `nonEmpty` method to `Stream`:

```
fun <T> Stream<T>.nonEmpty(): Optional<Stream<T>> {
    var nonEmptyStream: Stream<T>? = null
    val spliterator = this.spliterator()
    spliterator.tryAdvance {
        nonEmptyStream = Stream.concat(Stream.of(it), StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, this.isParallel)).onClose { this.close() }
    }
    if (nonEmptyStream == null) {
        this.close()
        return Optional.empty()
    }
    return Optional.of(nonEmptyStream!!)
}
```

The idea is to convert the stream into a `Spliterator` and try to take an element from that. If successful, I reconstruct the original stream by prepending the element to the rest of the stream. It seems to me that this should work for parallel streams as well but I might be overlooking something (not tested).